# Where should I ask questions about different Windows software

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have many questions regarding software that fails to start or I want to accomplish something using that software but its not really related to programming.

Is there good website like stack overflow where I can ask questions about my software.

Example:

- Something like 'how do I update my Photoshop' etc.
- How do I name a cd with my img burning tool etc.

I would prefer this to be a Stack Exchange website but if there are any others like it you can post them as well.

And just to make it clear it is ok to ask quesstions about software that is programming related on stack overflow right?

Comment: You're looking for [su].

Comment: thank you. do you know if its ok to ask questions about software that is programming related on stackoverflow??

Comment: Yes, that's perfectly fine. Have you read the [FAQ]? Super User has one, too, linked in the top header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Programming related-- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)
- Related to *using* programs/managing your computer --  [Super User](http://superuser.com)
- Related to managing large systems -- [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

There are more sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), though not all are relevant. If you're not sure about the on-topicness on a site, check the faq (top rightish corner, next to search bar). The first few entries of the faq tell you what you can and can't ask.

Comment: so just to make sure programming related programs are ok on stack overflow ?

Comment: @xitc yep. Though you may want to check out the faq of programmers.SE as well.

Comment: @TimManishEarth great you answered it... Xitcod13 same answer from my side... +1.